# BodePlot with wrong phase

Tags: plotting, control-systems

I'am trying to plot the function:

```
BodePlot[1/(1 + 0.1 s), s]
```

The phase plot is wrong (I'm using Mathematica 11.2):

[image]

Why does this happens and how can I get the right result?

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Works fine on my machine (Mma 11.3.0.0).

Comment: Hello @DavidG.Stork it is very strange. Maybe the version 11.2 has some bugs.

Comment: Works fine on my machine (Mma 10.2.0.0). Windows 8.1 64 bit

Comment: Try `BodePlot[1/(1 + 0.1 q)]`.

Comment: Hello @Hector, it works. It is very strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
BodePlot[
 TransferFunctionModel[
  {
   {1/(1 + 0.1 s)}
   }, s]
 , s
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Good solution @rhermans. In your opinion is it a bug?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi No, in my opinion the documentation for `BodePlot` is very clear and says *"The system lsys can be `TransferFunctionModel` or `StateSpaceModel`, including descriptor and delay systems."*

Comment: According to the documentation of `BodePlot`, the Op's syntax should work. Look at Generalizations & Extension, 1er example

Comment: Though, it's not exactly the same in the doc : there's only one argument. So `BodePlot[1/(1 + 0.1 s)]` should work

Comment: Hello @andre, yes your solution works.